# JQuery Client Failing outside localhost

Tags: javascript, jquery, client, client-server

Something pretty peculiar is happening with a simple JS GET client. Here's the code using JQuery:

```
<h3 onclick="$.ajax({
 url: 'http://147.102.82.124/',
 type: 'GET',                            
 error: function() { alert('FAILURE'); },
 success: function() {alert('SUCCESS')}
});">Click me</h3>
```

The method fires up a 'FAILURE' message unless the url is set to localhost. At the same time, the remote server replies with a 200 status code ( I checked using the web console of Firefox).

```
[15:06:59.135] GET http://147.102.82.124/ [HTTP/1.1 200 OK 9ms]
```

And ideas?

Comment: Any reason why the script is inline? You get the same failure if you attach the handler from external (or even in-page but non-inline) script?

Comment: @danwellman: that was just for testing... I think 3nigma gave the answer.

Comment: what you need is a server-side proxy script. Your page -> your server -> the other server. You can do this really easily with PHP+cURL

Comment: Quick tip: in you callback function write console.log(arguments) instead of alert failure this will display all the arguments passed to this function call. The jQuery object will have then passed to the function an error message and you should have read inside some sort of permission denied error

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As a security measure cross origin requests are not allowed, see [**CORS**](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-origin_resource_sharing)

Comment: Oh, OK! SO I guess when my web application will be deployed on http://myserver.org, then all requests to myserver.org will be eventually successful. Isn't it?

Comment: all requests from the pages served by `myserver.org` will be successful yes

Comment: Actually I tried again on localhost but using a different local domain name (defined in /etc/hosts) and it fails. It indeed requires that the request is sent to the same server. But just out of curiosity... Would it be possible to direct my requests to a different server?

Comment: Well, you're right! I should have followed the FGTA rule (First Google it, Then Ask...)

Answer (score 1):

I got the same issue and I solved using a server script which is always able to get the contents of a different domain.

So your ajax request needs to point to your local script (written using Java, PHP, Python or what ever,...) and your local script will be able to provide you the content of different domain.

Comment: Yes I know but this is one simple way to make it across different domain. Maybe also node.js will be able to make this task.